# insert date and time in MS Access using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

In my access database I have column timeStamp (Text) where I want to store the current date and time. The access db looks like

```
Id(autonumber) userName(text) Est_id(Number) timeStamp(text)
```

In c# I do this by

```
string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string date  = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

string my_querry = "INSERT INTO  savedSession (userName, Est_id, timeStamp) VALUES(@userName,@Est_id,@timeStamp)";
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_id", est_index);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", (date+" "+time));
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

the timeStamp is a text but I get error everytime I run the query. what should i change ? If I don't add timeStamp everything work perfectly

```
 string my_querry = "INSERT INTO  savedSession (userName, Est_id) VALUES(@userName,@Est_id)";
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(my_querry, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Est_id", est_index);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Did you try enclosing it with some single quotes like - cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", (string.format("'{0} {1}'",date,time)));

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]

Comment: where is your code related to userName & est_index initialization. is that initialized properly? which line of the code are you getting null reference exception?

Comment: the problem is with date and time.

Comment: But date and time looks good with respect to initialization, so may be issue is at some other line, so only asked about how you suspect date and time only ?

Comment: because when i remove the date/time column and just insert username and estIndex it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

NullReferenceException doesn't make any sense with the code you've provided.

One thing to try would be to concatenate the timestamp string outside of where you are adding the parameters and then just use a single variable in the parameters.AddWithValue method.

Another thing I can think of is that the way you are formatting the timestamp doesn't coincide with the correct format for the column in your database. If your column is a DateTime type then your formatting not C# isn't matching the correct masking required by access.

Answer (score 0):

You must supply a DateTime *value* when using *AddWithValue*:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@timeStamp", DateTime.Now);
```